# Angular - How to update page once a post button has been pressed?

Tags: angularjs

Ok so I have a Profile Settings page as below:

```
<form action="/profileSettings" method="post">
        Full Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" value='{[user.fullname]}'><br>
        About:<br>
        <input type="text" name="about" value='{[user.about]}'><br>
        Birthday:<br>
        <input type="text" name="birthday" value='{[user.birthday]}'><br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" value='{[user.email]}'><br>
        Location:<br>
        <input type="text" name="location" value='{[user.location]}'><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The data is passed back to it via an Angular controller, as below:

```
mainApp.controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.user = '';

    $http.get('/api/user', {params: { id: idFromSomewhere }})
        .success(function(res){
            $scope.user = res.user;
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
        });
}]);
```

The /api/user just chucks back a "profile has been updated" response to me when it has done it's bit. What I want to do is to:

- Make the post call via a button which updates the Profile Info. This semi works but I have to manually refresh the page to see the updated info.
- Handle the response which says "post has been updated" which I will then need to animate that on the site. No idea on this yet.
- Show the updated info on the Profile Settings page.

Seems like a very common thing and there must be something in Angular natively for it.

Any input will help guys. 
Thanks,
Shayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ng-submit
it will send the data back to the server and reloads the current page, you can check the reference here
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: Thanks for the ng-submit solution - I think this will work for me. I will give it a shot and update everyone here. Also, any ideas on the "you post has been updated" bit?

Comment: didn't get your question?

Comment: Let me have a proper think about it first before I officially ask :) - thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 2):

you can simply put your get call in a function and on success of your post call you can call the get function...the updated value will reflect without actually reloading or refreshing the page..

```
   $scope.func=funtion(){
  $http.get('/api/user', {params: { id: idFromSomewhere }})
            .success(function(res){
                $scope.user = res.user;
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
            });
}
```

and on success callback og your post...you can call this get method like this..

```
$http.post(...).success(function(){
$scope.func();
}
```